# how to combine try in the if condition

Tags: java, android

first code

```
try {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open("read_asset.txt");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        String text = new String(buffer);
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        tv.setText(text);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

and this second code

```
if(txtweb.getText().toString().equals("Google Plus")) {
        setContentView(R.layout.google);


    } else if(txtweb.getText().toString().equals("Twitter")){
        setContentView(R.layout.google);
    }
```

i want to combine try code into if condition , please help

Comment: what is wrong with just moving second into first code?

Comment: What do you do? your point is not clear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Like this:

```
try {
    if(txtweb.getText().toString().equals("Google Plus")) {
            setContentView(R.layout.google);
     InputStream is = getAssets().open("read_asset.txt");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            String text = new String(buffer);
            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
            tv.setText(text);
        } else if(txtweb.getText().toString().equals("Twitter")){
            setContentView(R.layout.google);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

Comment: its working bro , thanks

Comment: Why it is downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

You can process any function inside the try{} part of your first code. Did you try to copy second code and place it in try{} ? Is this what you are trying to achieve ?